# Understanding Haskell realToFrac function

Tags: kotlin, haskell

I meed to migrate some Haskell code to Kotlin and I have some confusion trying yo understand the next code:

```
floor ((realToFrac minutes :: Double) / 60)
```

minutes is a integer value, my Kotlin code, looks like this:

```
floor((minutes / 60).toDouble())
```

But I am not getting the expected results. I think I am missing the realToFrac part.

I do not have Haskell experience. If it possible could you give me some idea of this line of code in another language such Java or JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please add sample results and sample `minutes` values causing the difference?

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but I'd expect that with `floor(minutes.toDouble() / 60)`, you should get the same results as with the Haskell version.

Comment: @sjakobi tbh originally I added to comment the same approach. But from top of my head I was not able to find an example where it would fix things on positive minutes. I wonder if OP is using negative ones.

Comment: It's just converting an integer to a double.  Nothing too magical.

Comment: To compute the ratio between two integers, you have to convert them to floating point (double) _before_ taking the ratio. Otherwise, in most languages you get only the quotient, losing a lot of precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your Kotlin code is doing integer division and the Haskell code is doing division on `Double`s.

On the Kotlin side, if `minutes` is an integer, then so is `minutes / 60`. This will discard the remainder. You then convert to `double` and call `floor`, which will do nothing.

I think what you meant to do was:

```kotlin
floor(minutes.toDouble() / 60.0)
```

Which is equivalent to the Haskell code.